# Next.js Canary Updates

Tags: next.js

I'm running Next.js v12.3.0. There is a bug I need to fix and going by the GitHub issues, bumping Next.js up to the latest canary, or any version from `12.3.2 canary 10` would fix the bug. How to do go about implementing this bump up, and could there be any potential issues I could face by doing so?

Comment: "How to do go about implementing this bump up" - what does that mean? What keeps you from updating that library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canary versions in nextjs are relatively stable, and still follow the semver specification. To be safe, I recommend checking out a new git branch (`git checkout -b nextjs-canary-fix`), updating to the new version, and running a build to make sure everything works. If everything works, merge it into `main`. Another option would be to wait until `v12.3.2` is released.